# What's wrong with the review queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed

The review queue shows up like this:

[image]

And after I've reviewed it, I just get:

[image]

And it loads for a long time without anything happening. I closed my tab, opened it up again and after a while I got the same post to review, with the exact same results.

Comment: This is happening on my end, too, but I also know my Firefox is a bit out of date. What's your OS and browser, and are they up to date?

Comment: I tried it on my Mac OS High Sierra on Chrome and now on Windows 7 on Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit). But I didn't see it this way up until a few hours ago

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345602/156631